# Set DELETE in django-crispy-forms as first column

Tags: python, css, django, django-crispy-forms

I use the following code i my views.py to create my django-crispy-formset

```
 OrderLineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(OrderHeader, OrderLine, OrderLineForm, extra = 1, can_delete=True)
```

I added `can_delete= true` so i can remove rows, this works fine. However i am unable to set the layout of this object. It is automatically rendered to the end of the form, and also i you look closely it looks like it splits the last "column"  in two rows, see image below;

[image]

I use the following code to build my form;

```
class OrderLineForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OrderLineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = OrderLine

    fields = ['product_type', 'product','material','orderline_product_price','orderline_quantity',
              'orderline_total_price']
    labels = {
        'orderline_quantity': ('Quantity'),
        'orderline_product_price': ('Price'),
        'orderline_total_price': ('Total'),  
    }

class OrderLineFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderLineFormSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.template = 'bootstrap3/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.render_required_fields = True
        self.form_tag = False

    self.layout = Layout(
        #Div('DELETE',css_class="col-md-2"),
        #InlineCheckboxes('DELETE'),
        #PrependedText('DELETE', ''),
    )
```

Is there a way to show the DELETE in a proper way when using the crispy-forms template? And preferably at the beginning of the line in its own small column?

Comment: provide some `css_class` kwarg and play with css)

Comment: No, not yet, any ideas?